# Does AzureML RL support PyTorch?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Does AzureML RL support PyTorch?

As RLlib itself supports PyTorch as a framework, I tried to run AzureML RL with PyTorch but it failed.

I referred to [this page](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/rllib-training.html#common-parameters) to know how to specify the framework.

I added "framework":"torch" to my AzureML RL experiment's config but it failed.

Here're snippet from the training script.

```
tune.run(
    run_or_experiment="PPO",
    config={
        "env":"CartPole-v0",
        "env_config":env_config,
        "num_gpus":0,
        "num_workers":1,
        "callbacks":callbacks,
        "framework": "torch",
    },
    stop=stop,
    checkpoint_freq=2,
    checkpoint_at_end=True,
    local_dir='./logs',
```

Answer (score 2):

Ray's support for PyTorch exists, but is not nearly as extensive as its support for Tensorflow.

Whether or not PyTorch will work for your problem depends on the version of Ray/RLLib you're using, the algorithm you're running, and sometimes even the nature of the Environment (specifically the action and observation spaces).

I recommend starting by making sure you're using a recent version of Ray.  You can select a version by specifying a Pip package in the configuration for your `ReinforcementLearningEstimator` (this will be in your notebook code, not in the training script).  You can add code that looks something like this:

```
pip_packages=["ray[rllib]==0.8.7"]
```

Then in your `ReinforcementLearningEstimator` setup make sure you set `pip_packages`:

```
rl_estimator = ReinforcementLearningEstimator(    
    ...
    # Pip packages
    pip_packages=pip_packages,  
    ...
```